# Zend_Framework how to get the two URL Parameters

Tags: zend-framework

I have a build server (http://url.server.zip/release) which contains a list of zip files with some numeric numbers. E.g. http://url.server.zip/release/first_release_1,http://url.server.zip/release/first_release_2 and so on...

View: In my view page I have developed one search box from the search box, I need to search the string from that server (http://url.server.zip/release) then I have to display the release zip file in front view page.

```
public  function viewPostAction() {
  $this->params()->fromRoute('page', 1);
  return new ViewModel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really understand your question, but I'll give a try.

Regardless of your situation, in general, you'll have to set the two parameters' name in the route (module.config.php). Like this for example where I want to get in the url the id and name of a theme :

```
'theme' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/theme/[:themeId]/[:themeName]', 
                     ...
```

The `[]` means that it is not mandatory to use a parameter in the link. Up to you to know if you want to make it mandatory or not.

The URL would be something like "http://test.com/12/testing". Then, you'll be able to get both of the parameters this way:

```
$themeId = $this->params()->fromRoute('themeId');
$themeName = $this->params()->fromRoute('themeName');
```

$themeId = 12 and $themeName = testing, if we follow the example.

Hope it is what you were looking for. If not, could you maybe give us some more info ? Like your routing file, etc.